# Is it bad form to apply to a job twice?

Tags: job-search

A friend of mine sent me a job posting. I read the description, did some checking, and discovered that two months ago I had applied on Indeed.com to a job at the same company, that used the exact same job description.

This could be the same job, unfilled until now; or it could be a second opening for the same position. Perhaps they suspended the search to fill the job, and started over. In any case, they have my resume.

This time, however, my friend knows the recruiter and has given me her contact info. He recommends that I send my resume to her, mention that he referred me, and say how much I'd like the job.

But if there's a chance that she somehow remembers my previous application, won't this seem pushy? I didn't get a call back, after all.

**UPDATE:** I took your advice and sent my resume to the recruiter. Now I have a phone interview scheduled with the company. Clearly I was too timid, and having a referral helped. Thanks, all.

Comment: Some places are just slow... they might still be finding enough applicants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two months in between sounds very much like they didn't find a suitable candidate in the last round and have gone back out to market.  It won't hurt to reapply, if it is the case that they have decided to have another round, then perhaps they will re-evaluate their requirements.  Even if they've held it open to applications for all this time, then they obviously haven't found someone that they're satisfied with, especially if you didn't get any notification of being unsuccessful in your previous application.

Otherwise, you probably didn't lose much time doing the application, just see what happens.  You never know :)

Comment: But, isn't the fact that they never contacted me evidence of "unsuccessful in your previous application"?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson No, it's evidence that they haven't decided on a candidate.  It is _possible_ that you were unsuccessful and they just didn't notify you, but the fact you are seeing the ad again means that they are either still looking for the original role, or another similar role has opened.  Either way, putting in a second application isn't going to make you _less_ likely to get it if you haven't already got it :)

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson You could try. You lose absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. I did this and got the job. Circumstances change and applying a second time could look enthusiastic, which is a quality employers value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine. Especially if it's been a few month. You can possibly login to your online account with the company and withdraw your previous application. If this is a large company where each opening gets hundreds of applicants its possible that your first application was never reviewed anyway.

I was in a similar situation once, except I had no referral for the second time either. I had just made some modifications to my resume and I felt like it showcased my skills better so I sent it over. I got a call for an interview shortly afterward so they obviously didn't mind.